# How can I make Alfresco YUI validate prepopulated input fields and avoid "keyup"?

Tags: javascript, validation, yui, alfresco

I have a html form with some input fields that need validation:

```
<input type="text" id="hrs-edit-oib" name="oib">
```

I also have two validators on it. So with the new forms it works great. But with the prepopulated forms, it doesn't work.

I believe it is because the validators are set to work on a "keyup" event:

```
createEmployeeForm.addValidation("hrs-edit-oib", Alfresco.forms.validation.mandatory, null, "keyup");
```

Is there a way to tell the validator to process the form rigth away, if it has been prepopulated on the server side?

Here's an example: 
I load a page with markup:

```
"<input type="text" name="myid" value="preloaded" id="myid" />
```

And lets say that the value of "*myid*" needs to be longer then two chars (which is the case here). But there was no keyup and my Save button is disabled until I click into that field and press tab or something.

Thanks

Comment: Could you not just trigger the keyup event yourself?